# Intercept value changes within .blur() event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm using `.blur()` function to execute some code every time a text field loses focus (also when its value doesn't change).

Now I need to add some logic that must be executed only when text field value changes. Is there a way to combine `.change()` event with `.blur()`? Or, better, is there a way to know if the value in my text field is changed just using `.blur()`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not directly, but you can store the value on `focus` event..

something like

```
$('input')
    .on('focus',function(){
        // store the value on focus
        $(this).data('originalValue', this.value);
    })
    .on('blur',function(){
        // retrieve the original value
        var original = $(this).data('originalValue');

        // and compare to the current one
        if (original !== this.value){
            // do what you want
        }
    });
```

---

Of course you could just bind different handlers for each event..

```
$('input')
   .on('change', function(){/*your change code*/})
   .on('blur', function(){/*your blur code*/});
```

Comment: `$('input')
   .change(function(){/*your change code*/})
   .blur(function(){/*your blur code*/});` could work?

Comment: @davioooh, yes because all jQuery methods are chainable.. (*unless they are getters of some specific value*)

Comment: The first one works awesome to minimize server requests for a new user form signup.

Answer (score 3):

The event change is trigger every time that the field lose the focus and the content has change. I think what you need is to use `change()` instead of `blur()`. Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dVjxP/)

```
$('#in').change(function(){
    alert('change!');
});
```

If what you need is to execute the same code when the input loses the focus and when the value changes, you can combine both events

```
$('in').on('change blur', function(){
   //code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use closure to store the previous value and compare them later

```
var createOnBlurFunc = function(){
    var prevVal = '';
    return function(e){
        if(prevVal === $(this).val()){
           //same value
        } else {
           prevVal = $(this).val();
           // do something
        }
     }
};
$('input').blur(createOnBlurFunc());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a more generalized way, for those that are created on the fly:

```
var $bodyEl = $('body'), inputOldValue;

$bodyEl.on('focus', 'input, textarea, select', function () {
    inputOldValue = $(this).val();
});
$bodyEl.on('blur', 'input, textarea, select', function () {
    if (inputOldValue != $(this).val()) {
        $(this).trigger('changeBlur');
    }
});
```

`input, textarea, select` is faster than `:input` as a selector.