# jQuery change-and-then-blur event

Tags: jquery, events, blur

We have one of those scenarios where you prefer an event to be triggered only when you leave the input field. That is because the event leads to a "postback" like ajax request which in turn updates the input fields. A change event would start an infinite loop.

On the other end, a blur event is triggered each time the user leaves the field regardless whether the field was changed or not.

What I am looking for is kind of a "change-and-then-blur" event which fires *if* the field changed but only *when* it is left (blurred).

I reckon jQuery does not have that out of the box. Is there any easy way to extend it for that?

**Update - I have just tried hard to reproduce the issue of the infinite loop in a simple jsfiddle - to no avail.**

There is knockout involved as well as jQuery autoNumeric and a custom autoNumeric knockout binding. The values are updated using ko.mapping. But even when including all of those my jsfiddle seems to work perfectly with the simple jQuery `change` event: http://jsfiddle.net/a1tbxnpp/

So I guess I will rather investigate the issue with my application that bother introducing another jQuery event.

Comment: I didn't understand completely your problem... The change event is only called once, if you want to be sure the fields is not focused, just check if it's focused... http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/  But the change event mainly occurred when field is blurred.

Comment: @Loenix - you are completely right. I updated my question. I cannot "revoke" it since it already has an answer. Nor can I close it with immediate effect.

Comment: please check this out [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710227/intercept-value-changes-within-blur-event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710227/intercept-value-changes-within-blur-event)

Answer (score 2):

Why not using focus and blur. On focus save the value of the input field in a variable. On blur compare the value of the input with the variable, if it's different do the ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

Well... answering my own question, I have just tried the following and it seems to work in the first place:

```
$(":input").each(function() {
    var $el = $(this),
        oldValue = $el.val();

    $el.focus(function() {
        oldValue = $el.val();
    });

    $el.blur(function() {
        var newValue = $el.val();
        if (oldValue != newValue) {
            $el.trigger('changeblur');
        }
    });
});
```

I guess there is no simpler answer than that...

Comment: This works, but for elements that are created on the fly we have to do something like this: `var inputOldValue;   $('body').on('focus', 'input, textarea, select', function(){ inputOldValue = $(this).val(); });     $('body').on('blur', 'input, textarea, select', function () {  if (inputOldValue != $(this).val()) {  $(this).trigger('changeBlur'); }   });`   And I used `'input, textarea, select'` here instead of `':input'`, because the former is faster than the latter.